# Reactjs list event binding using useMemo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not sure, if I've chosen the right solution for this case, but I couldn't find anything better. I need to implement a picker with tracking the picked option and carriage pointing to that, therefore current picked option must be accessible from any other option element (e.g. it should be possible to `console.log` current picked option when `onMouseLeave` event is triggered on any other option).

I used `useMemo` for creating the list from `props.options` which will be rendered with map as shown here:

```
    const [pickedElement, setPickedElement] = useState("");


    const move_to_picked = () => {
        console.log(pickedElement);
    }


    const optionsList = useMemo(() => {
        let answer = [];
        for (let item of options)
            answer.push(
              <div
                key={item}
                onClick={() => setPickedElement(item)}
                onMouseLeave={move_to_picked}
              >
                <p>{item}</p>
              </div>
            );
        return answer;
    }, [options]);
```

However, `move_to_picked` func which was triggered by event logged the initial state of `pickedElement` variable. After some research, I've came up to the idea, that after picking new option, `move_to_picked` function is reassigned to 'new' version, but is not rebinded in `optionsList`. After adding `pickedElement` to `useMemo` dependencies everything works fine, but I'm worried about looping over whole array just because of picking new option. Does `useState` hook works like mentioned above (creating new version of the function), and if so:

1. Is there any way to not to reassign `move_to_picked` function, so there won't be any need in rebinding it (therefore in looping over an array either)?
2. Maybe the entire solution of this case is wrong, then what is the right one?

Comment: What's the reason you're using `useMemo` in the first place? I assume for performance, but specifically *what* performance? In other words, what do you do later in your code with `optionsList`, which requires a stable array reference?

Comment: @NicholasTower ```OptionList``` is passed once and never changes after, it's used for rendering list of options in picker element, so I thought it's neccessary to avoid recalculating that list as it might be quite long. As long as I know, ```useMemo``` can help with that

Comment: @NicholasTower Is it a misuse, and if so, what should I use instead? The main problem is that after pickedElement changes, function that is binded to onMouseLeave in each option refers to the initial value of pickedElement (which is correct for the time of binding), is there a way to fix that, without iterating over whole array?

Comment: Memoizing the creation of react elements is not going to save much time, because the creation of react elements is cheap. They're just plain javascript objects. The eventual *rendering* of those elements could conceivably be expensive, but your code won't stop that. My initial reaction is to recommend that you should not use `useMemo` here. If you don't agree, feel free to edit your question to show what you do with `optionsList` later in the code. The lines you showed don't justify using useMemo, but later lines might.

Comment: @NicholasTower I've finally managed to solve the problem with useRef instead of useState for pickedElement. But now I feel like I'm misunderstanding the concept of useMemo. I thought, if the optionsList will stay the same, it won't be rerendered, because nothing has changed. That's why I've chosen useMemo. If useMemo doesn't save from rerendering, are there any ways for doing this? For rendering optionsList I just insert it like ```{optionsList}```

Comment: An element like `<div>{/* etc *}</div>` is just a small object describing what you want react to render next. Eg, `{ type: 'div', props: { /*...*/} }`. As you render, you create these and return them. After you return, react recurses to the children and renders each of those. It does *not* compare these objects to the previous render, so memoizing them makes no difference. Once the recursive process is complete and entire virtual dom is known, *then* it will do a diff to determine which parts of the real dom need to be updated.

Comment: If you want to skip rendering a component, the tool for that is [React.memo](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo). But otherwise, react is designed so that if one component renders, all of its children render also.

Comment: I've recently found out that part of my comments is incorrect. React apparently *does* compare the `{ type: 'div', props: { /* ... */ }}` object and skip rendering. So `useMemo` can skip rendering. Sorry for misinforming you. I was proven wrong in the comments of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77054082/3794812