# How to have a timer component without re-rendering other components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a timer component in React/React Native. I got the timer to work and display, but then I noticed that the functions I use to render in my child components are called every second. I am guessing that they are re-rendered because the state changed, but I only want the timer text to be re-rendered and not my other child components. Every tutorial I came across does the same thing so I do not know how to handle this.

Here is a code snippet of what I am trying to solve:

```
const ParentComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [ellapsedSeconds, setEllapsedSeconds] = React.useState<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
     const interval = setInterval(() => {
       setEllapsedSeconds((prevTime) => {
         return prevTime + 1
       });
     }, 1000);

     return () => {
       clearInterval(interval);
     };
  }, [ellapsedSeconds]);

  const renderTime = (): string => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(ellapsedSeconds / 60);
    const seconds = ellapsedSeconds % 60;
    return `${minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:${
      seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds
    }`;
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{renderTime()}</Text>
      <ChildComponent/>
    </View>
  );
};

const ChildComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const renderComponent = (): ReactNode => {
    console.log("How to stop this from running repeatedly?")
    // return some components
  }

  return (
    <View>
       {renderComponent()}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I only want the timer text to be re-rendered and not my other child components. Here are what I have tried:

- Separating timer to another component: It works and does not repeatedly trigger the functions, but only if the ellapsedSeconds state is kept inside that timer component and is not passed from the parent component. If I want my parent component to keep the state then the functions repeat again.
- Using useRef instead of useState for ellapsedSeconds: Functions are not called repeatedly now, but the timer text is not updated either no matter what I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options then either you render the second component in a useMemo hook and then use that result in your render block or you can surround your second component with React.memo.

Here is an example with a useMemo hook:

```
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import React, {useMemo, useEffect} from 'react'

const ChildComponent = () => {
  console.log("Render second component")

  return (
    <View>
       <Text>Second component</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [ellapsedSeconds, setEllapsedSeconds] = React.useState<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
     const interval = setInterval(() => {
       setEllapsedSeconds((prevTime) => {
         return prevTime + 1
       });
     }, 1000);

     return () => {
       clearInterval(interval);
     };
  }, [ellapsedSeconds]);

  const renderTime = (): string => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(ellapsedSeconds / 60);
    const seconds = ellapsedSeconds % 60;
    return `${minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:${
      seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds
    }`;
  };

  const children = useMemo(() => (<ChildComponent />), [])

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{renderTime()}</Text>
      {children}
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ParentComponent />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

And here with the React.memo

```
import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import React, {useMemo, useEffect} from 'react'

const ChildComponent = React.memo(() => {
  console.log("Render second component")

  return (
    <View>
       <Text>Second component</Text>
    </View>
  );
})

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [ellapsedSeconds, setEllapsedSeconds] = React.useState<number>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
     const interval = setInterval(() => {
       setEllapsedSeconds((prevTime) => {
         return prevTime + 1
       });
     }, 1000);

     return () => {
       clearInterval(interval);
     };
  }, [ellapsedSeconds]);

  const renderTime = (): string => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(ellapsedSeconds / 60);
    const seconds = ellapsedSeconds % 60;
    return `${minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:${
      seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds
    }`;
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{renderTime()}</Text>
        <ChildComponent />
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ParentComponent />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: `const children = useMemo(() => (<ChildComponent />), [])` This is not going to make a meaningful difference. `<ChildComponent />` just means `React.createElement(ChildComponent)`, and the time to execute createElement is trivial, since it just creates a small javascript object describing what to render next. *Rendering* the component may not be trivial, but this line of code doesn't stop it from rendering.

Comment: Yes and no. Obviously it will be rendered in the first place as you want to see in on the screen, but for every future rerender of the ParentComponent there is no additional render of the ChildComponent, which can save a lot of resources for complex or slow child components. You can validate that by executing my code and check how often the "Render second component" log gets printed.

See my snack here: https://snack.expo.dev/@baumstumpf/stackoverflow-timer-child-rendering